# Как задать маску формата в функции to_number() для знака минуса в начале или конце строки?

Tags: sql, oracle

Есть символьная колонка, в которой могут быть представлены отрицательные значения в двух различных форматах: знак минуса в конце и, как обычно, в начале.

До сих пор пробовал следующее, но для каждого значения, один из них выводит ошибку формата, а другой работает, и наоборот:

```
SELECT
    str,
    to_number(str, 'fm999.99mi') AS opt1,
    to_number(str, 'fm999.99') AS opt2
FROM (
    SELECT '-92.93' AS str FROM dual
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '92.93-' AS str1 FROM dual)
```

> ORA-01722: invalid number

Ожидаемый вывод:

| str | opt1 | opt2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| -92.93 | -92.93 | -92.93 |
| 92.93- | -92.93 | -92.93 |

Можно ли обединить их, чтобы работало для обоих числовых форматов?

---

PS: версия 12.1.0.2.0

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Oracle SQL format mask to_number](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67316410) от участника [@jeiv](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15746603/jeiv)</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/67316410

Answer (score 3):

Маска формата это символьное значение, которое может быть составлено по условию:

```
select str,
    to_number(str, 'fm999.99'||case substr (str, -1) when '-' then 'mi' end) res
from (
    select '-92.93' str from dual
    union all
    select '92.93-' str1 from dual)
/
```

Результат:

```
STR           RES
------ ----------
-92.93 -92,93    
92.93- -92,93
```